# Unable to navigate to another screen in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using props in my code to show items but I am not able to navigate to any other screen after click on it. I am also define as `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` but showing me error as in screen shot.

Here is my code. This code is in same `Indprotype.js` file (two separate .js files are not used)

```
  class Withwish extends React.Component {

      ProPressed(productid){
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        const params = { productid };
        navigate('Product', params);
      }

    render() {
          // const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      return (
                  <View style={styles.word}>
                  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.ProPressed(this.props.id)}>
                    <Image source={{uri: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/hu2lcbj2n/' + this.props.image}} />
                  </TouchableHighlight>  
              </View>
      );
    }
  }


  export default class Indprotype extends React.Component {
     // const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    render() {
       const items = this.state.qwerty.data;
      return (
          <GridView
              renderItem={item => (
                <Withwish
                  image = {item.p1.image}
                  id = {item.p1.id}
                 />
            )}
          />
      );
    }
  }
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

Basically I'm passing the `navigation` prop from the `Indprotype` component through to the `Withwish` component.

Note: I'm assuming here that `Indprotype` itself receives the `navigation` prop from a router or similar.

```
class Withwish extends React.Component {

    ProPressed(productid){
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      const params = { productid };
      navigate('Product', params);
    }

  render() {
        // const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
                <View style={styles.word}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.ProPressed(this.props.id)}>
                  <Image source={{uri: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/hu2lcbj2n/' + this.props.image}} />
                </TouchableHighlight>  
            </View>
    );
  }
}


export default class Indprotype extends React.Component {
    // const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  render() {
      const items = this.state.qwerty.data;
    return (
        <GridView
            renderItem={item => (
              <Withwish
                navigation = {this.props.navigation}
                image = {item.p1.image}
                id = {item.p1.id}
                />
          )}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yehhh... it worked. Thank you so much I tried before but but passed like `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` but it was wrong.